# MySQL Select with Range from Numbers at two Rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a Problem!

I will get the right User, with the Right Tickets.
Users have in MySQL Tickets from a Range.
Like this (example)
User1 have Tickets "from: 0.01 - to: 1.00"
User2 have tickets "from: 1.01 - to: 11.00"

I tested it with this MySQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM `round` WHERE `from` <= '$choosedticket' AND `to` >= '$choosedticket'
```

but there i get much times the wrong User. I need the Correctly User...

Like when choosed Ticket ist 17.00 than i need user where have this Range Tickets. With the MySQL Query, i get much times wrong User.

It looks Like this:
`SELECT * FROM`round`WHERE`from`<= '17.00' AND`to`>= '17.00'`
Than much times he choosed user with 1.70 or like this and not the correct user...

Comment: Why not also select on your userid to only get that user. Are you storing your time as a string or number?

Comment: Are you sure your data is correct? Meaning do only the designated users have tickets in the given range?

Comment: What is the datatype of `from` and `to`? If they're strings, you need to convert them to numbers before comparing, because the string `101.0` is less than the string `20.0`.

Comment: Also, you can use `BETWEEN`: `WHERE $choosedticket BETWEEN from AND to`. But you still need to convert everything to numbers.

Comment: the current query will only return result if the field `from` and `to` both meet the condition. this means if for one row `from` is 12 and  `to` is 12 the row will not be returned as the considtion for `to` is not greater than 17.00

Comment: @Memor-X It sounds like `from` and `to` will never be the same, they define a range of values for that user.

Comment: also as @Barmar mentioned you shouldn't be doing numerical checking such as *greater/less than or equals to* to strings. since it appears they are floats you should be passing in float values not strings

Comment: @Barmar i used it as an example. `to` could be anything less than 17 and it would still fail. to me it seems as if `from` and `to` should actually be one field and the [BETWEEN Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) used to do the filtering

Comment: How could `to` be less than `from`? They're a range from lowest to highest ticket numbers.